# spring-boot upgrade from 2.4 to 2.7.8 and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I've upgraded my project to spring 2.7.8 and having difficulties to run tests. The project is compiling, but more than half of the current tests is failing.
Parent org.springframework.boot - version 2.7.8, java 11
My pom looks like this:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa</groupId>
        <artifactId>xsuaa-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.pivotal.cfenv</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-cfenv</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifact4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any ideas? Followed some other threads about it but none of them solved the issue.

Comment: Remove junit4 and all the excludes for `spring-boot-starter-test` and remove the version from `spring-security-test`. Spring Boot 2.7 uses a newer Mockito version then you are currently supporting with Powermock, do you really ned power mock?

Answer (score -1):

From my experience sometimes when you want to upgrade some version of spring, or spring security for an example from spring sec 5 to spring sec 6 you can encounter to a problems like this (in spring sec 6 they have completely removed **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** and almost nothing will work after upgrade). They have changed the implementation in the libraries.

**Try to downgrade your version**, or try to track changes between spring and testing library.

Comment: He has a problem with Mockito not Sprig Security.